# is there some line of code in phpword to setup papersize in docx to pdf convertion

Tags: php, pdf, docx, dompdf, phpword

I'm trying to convert an existing docx file to pdf with domPDF and PHPWord, and everything works fine, but the resultant file is A4 size, and the original docx file is Letter, the resultant file must be letter too, what can I do? please help.

```php
$existingfile='../../CC BB03-04-30.docx';

Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
Settings::setPdfRendererPath('../../dompdf-master/vendor/');

$phpWord = IOFactory::load($existingfile, 'Word2007');
$phpWord->save('../../test.pdf', 'PDF');
```

Like I said, the code works fine, the only issue that I'm trying to solve, is the paper size. I need letter size to the PDF file.

Comment: Try
    $paper = new Paper();  
    $paper->setSize('Letter');  
    $phpWord->addSection(['pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight()]);

Comment: Hi Andrea, thank you for your attention, I had try your code but it gives me this error: 
 Uncaught Error: Class 'Paper' not found

I think that I got PHPWord files incomplete. Im going to download PHPWord again

Comment: I already downloaded PHPWord with composer, but still it gives me Paper class not found error

Comment: Sorry @alexismanotas, are you using phpoffice/phpword 0.16.0? Try `$paper = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper(); $paper->setSize('Letter'); $phpWord->addSection(['pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight()]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

Php:

```
Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
Settings::setPdfRendererPath('../../dompdf-master/vendor/');

$paper = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper();
$paper->setSize('Letter');  
$phpWord = IOFactory::load($existingfile, 'Word2007');

$phpWord->addSection(['pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight()]);
$phpWord->save('../../test.pdf', 'PDF');
```

Comment: hello Andrea, again thank you very much for all your attention, great, the class error is gone, but the file resultant still has A4 size. what can I do? I check the file resultant size in photoshop and still is 210 x 297 mm

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who still have this issue, I was experiencing the same problem. I tried modifying several different things and in the end I found that the culprit here was PHPWord's DomPDF writer function.

The file you are looking for is:

```
vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF/DomPDF.php
```

Basically what I found out was that the DomPDF `save()` function had A4 hardcoded as paper size.

The original function is this one:

```php
public function save($filename = null)
{
    $fileHandle = parent::prepareForSave($filename);

    //  PDF settings
    $paperSize = 'A4';
    $orientation = 'portrait';

    //  Create PDF
    $pdf = $this->createExternalWriterInstance();
    $pdf->setPaper(strtolower($paperSize), $orientation);
    $pdf->loadHtml(str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $this->getContent()));
    $pdf->render();

    //  Write to file
    fwrite($fileHandle, $pdf->output());

    parent::restoreStateAfterSave($fileHandle);
}
```

So, basically what I did was modify the `$paperSize` variable to `'letter'` and it worked. The only thing I am not sure is what would happen if composer updated PHPWord, but I guess you can always download the library separately and modify that parameter. I am going to report it in their Github for future reference.